# Contact Us button/smtplib forward details

Tags: html, flask, smtplib, pythonanywhere

I am using pythonanywhere to make a website. I have set up a contact us page, and I am attempting to take whatever a user submits as feedback and then forward the information to myself with smtplib. I asked about this on their forums, but they for some reason just deleted my post.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<title>Contact us!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/contact.css') }}">
<div class="container">
  <form action="contact">


    <label for="report">Reason</label>
    <select id="report" name="report">
      <option value="Bug">Bug</option>
      <option value="Suggestion">Suggestion</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>

    <label for="Subject">Subject</label>
    <textarea id="Subject" name="Subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

  </form>
</div>
```

And here is the python code:

```
@app.route("/contact", methods=["GET", "POST"])

def feedback():

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("contact.html")
    else:
        result = "Thanks for the feedback!"
        report = request.form['report']
        Subject = request.form['Subject']

        from email.mime.text import MIMEText
        import smtplib
        gmail_user = 'email@gmail.com'
        gmail_password = 'password'

        message = MIMEText(report)
        message["Subject"] = Subject
        message["From"] = gmail_user
        message["To"] = gmail_user

        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
        server.sendmail(gmail_user, gmail_user, message.as_string())
        server.close()
        return render_template('settlement_return.html',result = result)
```

EDIT: If I manually set report and subject to some misc text string it sends fine. But trying to get the information that someone submits is not giving any results.

Comment: What response do you get from your view when that form is submitted to the view -- the results of rendering your `settlement_return.html` template, or something else?  If you get an error message, is there anything in your site's error log?

Comment: When I hit submit it returns me to a fresh /contact page. It does not error out, but never appears to make it into the else statement.

Comment: That sounds like you're getting a GET request, then -- what happens if you add a `method="POST"` to your `form` tag in the HTML?

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you so much!

Comment: Excellent, thanks for confirming!  I've put the fix into an answer below, it would be great if you could mark it as the official correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above -- it looks like the problem was that you were missing the `method="POST"` in your `form` tag.  That meant that the form was being submitted with the `GET` method, so the code in the first branch of the `if` statement in your view was being executed, which meant that no email was being sent.